# Trigger a workflow manually from GitHub action

Tags: android, github-actions

I'm using GitHub actions to run the CI for an Android app project.
I have a workflow that works well. It runs on PRs and it runs the tests and builds the app.

I have reused the workflow code to build a new one that I put in a different `yml` file in the same folder.

The difference is that this workflow has a `workflow_dispatch` as event. It also takes one input. It runs the tests and then it will publish the build on Goolge Play or Firebase. For now I'm just using some `echo` to log what's happening.

Reading the documentation I was expecting to see a button to manually trigger the workflow from the GitHub UI.

I don't see the workflow when I click on the Action tab and so I don't see the button.
If I make a mistake like for example I delete all the jobs then I see the workflow because I get failed `run`. The button is not visible anyway.

```
name: Publish On CI

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      publish:
        description: 'Choose where you want to publish the build'
        required: true
        default: AppTester
        type: choice
        options:
          - GooglePlay
          - AppTester
          - Both

env:
  ANDROID_KEYS_FOLDER: ..

jobs:
  publish:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: decode keys
        run: echo "${{ secrets.APP_PROPERTIES_BASE64 }}" | base64 > app.properties
          echo "${{ secrets.APP_RELEASE_BASE64 }}" | base64 > app-release
      - name: set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: gradle

      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew
      - name: Run Unit test
        run: ./gradlew testStagingUnitTest
      - name: Build
        run: ./gradlew :app:assembleStaging
      - name: Publish on Google Play if required
        if: inputs.publish == 'GooglePlay'
        run: echo "Publishing on Google Play"
      - name: Publish on Firebase if required
        if: inputs.publish == 'AppTester'
        run: echo "Publishing on Firebase"
      - name: Publish on Google Play and Firebase if required
        if: inputs.publish == 'Both'
        run: echo "Publishing on Google Play and Firebase"
```

Comment: Is the workflow on the repo `default` branch?

Comment: no it isn't. Does it need to be on the default? It shows an error when I make a mistake in the script so it looks like it is running

Comment: To appear on the Github UI, the workflow with the `dispatch_event` trigger needs to exist on the default branch `yes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workflow with the `workflow_dispatch` trigger needs to exist on the **repository default branch** to appear on the Github User Interface `Actions` tab.